# Artifactory upload missing modules

Tags: android, maven, gradle, repository, artifactory

i try to upload an .aar file to an Artifactory Server. Im using artifactoy plugin :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.6.1'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.13.0' // version plugin support
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.5"
    }
}
```

I read quite a lot of documentation last 2 days and cant figure out why the following is not working:

First of all i do not understand how the artifactory plugin decides which repository it should take to upload the *.aar file ?
In Artifactory are two kind of endpoint to upload for internal use: **lib-release-local** and **lib_snapshot**

In my build.gradle in project root i define them:

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'https://servername/artifactory/libs-release-local'
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }

    maven {
        url 'https://servername/artifactory/libs-snapshot'
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
}


artifactoryPublish.skip = true

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

My Second Problem is that Artifactory Plugin uploads something, i see this log entry:

```
Deploying build descriptor to: https://servername/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under https://servername/artifactory/webapp/builds/eap-androidcore/1475772844540
```

On the Artifactory Web UI I see only something got uploaded in the "Build Browser". There are no modules listed, the *.aar file is missing. Also no POM gets generated at all like in any other maven repositories.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.example.core'
            artifactId project.name
            version = VERSION_NAME
            artifact "${project.buildDir}/build/outputs/aar/core_icons-debug.aar"
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the path to the file couple of times, it's correct.

So why does artifactory not upload the .aar file ?

Many thanks for reading/helping me

Comment: You may want to compare what you did with https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en I'll check tomorrow what else I can find out

Comment: Well, thats using Bintray as a repo.